# strange javascript grammar when calling a function

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am learning javascript sample from this page,

http://nofunc.org/AJAX_Star_Rating

my questions are (1),

for function function XY(e,v), it has two input parameters e and v, but it is called with only one parameter x=XY(e), how does it work?

question (2), I am confused about what this function XY is doing below, especially confused about the grammar `{'X':e.pageX,'Y':e.pageY}` and `v?o[v]:o`, could anyone explain what do they mean please?

```
var o=agent('msie')?{'X':event.clientX+document.documentElement.scrollLeft,'Y':event.clientY+document.documentElement.scrollTop}:{'X':e.pageX,'Y':e.pageY}; return(v?o[v]:o); }
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I've worked with this plugin before. I don't particularly like the terse and compact style in which it is written.

Comment: Agree, Alex. Do you have any alternative samples to implement the same "star" effect? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function XY(e,v)` is an event handler. First argument is the event object passed to the function, second is the element affected. The function is called automatically by Javascript when the relevant event is triggered.

`{'X':e:pageX, 'Y':e:pageY}` are just key-value pairs. Essentially, an "array" with identifiers for each element and a value corresponding to that identifier. Strictly speaking, Javascript doesn't have "arrays". They're called objects. The identifiers are called properties.

`v?o[v]:o` translates to `if (v) return o[v]; else return o;` Ternary expressions, as they are known, also appear in the last line. `if (agent('msie')) var o={'X':event...}; else var o={'X':e.pageX,...};`

Comment: Thanks! I am confused about "v?o[v]:o", since v does not appear in function XY(e, v), any ideas? What value it returns?

Comment: As mentioned, `v` - being the 2nd arg - is the element affected by the event.

Comment: I want to confirm with you that if I am using Internet Explorer, then "{'X': event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft, 'Y': event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop}" should be executed, and "{'X': e.pageX, 'Y': e.pageY }" should not executed, correct?

Comment: (1) "is the element affected by the event" -- so for mouse move event, it is the object which mouse moves over correct? (2) But what is o[v] in the scenario of mouse move event? For the ul element whose id="star"?

Comment: (1) yes. (2) `o` is the variable holding the result of the preceding `if (agent('msie'))`. get the idea?

Comment: Thanks stillstanding, I almost get the idea, just final confirmation with you -- I read the code again, and I think in mouse move event, since v is undefined (since we call XY with only one paramter, which is XY(e)), return (v ? o[v] : o) results in o, correct?

Comment: "you got the hang of it already" -- sorry English is not my native language. Do you mean my understanding of return (v ? o[v] : o) results in o, is correct in mouse move scenario when we call XY with only one paramter?

Comment: `(",)` yes, because v is undefined

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a very loose coupling between formal parameters and active parameters. Your function `function XY(e,v)` can in reality be called with any number of parameters. Parameters that are not ‘filled’ at the call site get the special value `undefined`. When the function is called with more parameters than in the parameter list, these extra parameters are accessible through a special variable `arguments`. This is an Array-ish object of all active parameters the function was called with. (So, including those that don't have names.)

Regarding your second question, `{}` is object literal notation. You basically create an object there and then, and set its `X` and `Y` attributes.

The `v?o[v]:o` construct is the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_operator#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript) for if-then-else. In pseudo-code, you can read it as `if v then o[v] else o`. (This is similar to C/C++, if you've seen it before.)

Comment: Thanks! I am confused about "v?o[v]:o", since v does not appear in function XY(e, v), any ideas? What value it returns?

Comment: I want to confirm with you that if I am using Internet Explorer, then "{'X': event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft, 'Y': event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop}" should be executed, and "{'X': e.pageX, 'Y': e.pageY }" should not executed, correct?